# Enable default touch effect for Android Button control

Tags: android, button, touch

Working on first native android application, I created button like this

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/yesPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorApprove"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

When I run on Android device and tap the button, there is no touch/tap effect showing the user that the button is active. Do i need to add some directive to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , just replace with your own `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to your
button.